# Foerach Multiples lista una sola linea

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un foreach de dos listas pero que en cada linea me diga:

```
Tengo 5 Naranjas
Tengo 6 Peras
Tengo 2 Platanos
```

No encuentro la forma y tiene que ser bastante tonto hacerlo pero estoy empezando con python.

```
items = ['naranjas', 'peras', 'platanos']

nums = [5, 6, 2]

# without indexes
for item in items:
    print("Tengo" + str(nums) + str(items))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es recorrer el indice de la siguiente manera:

```
items = ['naranjas', 'peras', 'platanos']

nums = [5, 6, 2]

# without indexes
for index in range(len(items)):
    print("Tengo" + str(nums[index]) + str(items[index]))
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 4):

Hay varias formas, lo más práctico ya que ambas listas son de igual cantidad de elementos, es "juntar" ambas listas mediante `zip()`  el que te retorna un iterador de tuplas dónde el primer elemento es la fruta y el segundo la cantidad.

```
items = ['naranjas', 'peras', 'platanos']
nums = [5, 6, 2]

for fruta, numero in zip(items, nums):
    print("Tengo {} {}".format(numero, fruta))
```

La otra posibilidad, sería usar de alguna forma un índice, por ejemplo el que retorna un `enumerate()`:

```
for i,item in enumerate(items):
    print("Tengo " + str(nums[i]) +  ' ' + str(item))
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar la función map y una función lambda, quizas es mas eficiente ya que solo escribe en la consola una sola vez.

```
items = ['naranjas', 'peras', 'platanos']
nums = [5, 6, 2]

result = map(lambda x, y: "Tengo " +  str(x) + " " + y, nums, items) 
print("\n".join(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

Te muestro un ejemplo en el cual se utiliza un poco mas la lógica que un método es para reforzar tu sentido de programación, debes aprender a utilizar los arreglos y sus llamadas individuales y como funcionan las secuencias.

```
items = ['naranjas', 'peras', 'platanos']
i=0
nums = [5, 6, 2]
# without indexes
for item in items:
    print("Tengo " + str(nums[i]) +  " " + str(item))
    i=i+1
```